# My cider stopped fermenting after it accidentally got opened and darkened in color

Tags: troubleshooting, cider

I am making a Pom Cider and the bubbler cap got taken off my cider, 2 days later it has stopped fermenting and is darkening in color. Is it done? Is is bad? Can I fix it?

Thanks
~~J

Answer (score 1):

How long had it been fermenting before the cap got removed?   I've never brewed a cider, but beer and mead both darken in color as the yeast fall out of suspension.   Pull a sample and check the gravity and the flavor.   It may be just fine.

Comment: It had been 9 days when the lid was uncapped.

Comment: bah your fine, I have left mine open the entire time before (probably not the best idea) and they have turned out fine.